# rspec - "after it" - how to change from should to expect syntax?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I change from `should` to `expect` for the `it` in this code:-

```
context 'class_name' do
  before do
    Fabricator(:some_company, :class_name => Company) do
      name 'Hashrocket'
    end
  end
  after { Fabrication.clear_definitions }
  its(:name) { should == 'Hashrocket' }
  it { should be_kind_of(Company) }
end
```

I can see that the `its` will probably be:

```
 expect(name.to eq 'Hashrocket')
```

but what should the `it { should be_kind_of(Company) }` become given the implicit subject.
Would it be

```
  expect(it).to be_kind_of(Company)
```

?

I don't have the project set up yet from github (it is large).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to change the short-form `it` blocks to the `expect` syntax. One of the reasons for the new syntax is to avoid the monkeypatching required to add `should` to every object. The short-form `it` blocks already avoid this problem.

However, if you need to access the implicit subject, you can say

```
expect(subject).to be_kind_of(Company)
```

Although I prefer to name my subjects explicitly:

```
subject(:company) { Company.new }

it 'something' do
  expect(company).to be_kind_of(Company)
end
```

Comment: You can also use `is_expected` as a shortcut for `expect(subject)`: `it { is_expected.to be_a Company }`, and `its(:name) { is_expected.to eq 'Hashrocket' }`.